# How to echo portion of UTF-8 varchar string with MySQL if the string is more than certain number of characters?

Tags: php, text, utf-8, substr

I'm currently using the substr() function which works fine for characters written in english. But when I apply that to characters written in greek, the text is cut with a strange character (a questionmark inside a diamond shape) appearing before the 3 fullstops (...). 
Below is the code, thanks:

```
$string //a varchar string written in greek and called from the database 
if (strlen($string) > 200) {
    echo substr($string, 0, 200).'...';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [multibyte functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) like so:

```
mb_internal_encoding( "UTF-8" );

if( mb_strlen( $string ) > 200 ) {
   echo mb_substr( $string, 0, 200 ) . "...";
}
```

The normal functions work on bytes and don't have any character awareness like you are expecting from them. Text using common english characters in UTF-8 are all 1 byte per character, so the normal functions accidentally work for them.

Comment: That worked just fine, thanks. Is there any way to also keep whole words instead cutting it from the middle?

Comment: @KokosKoka you'd need to do smarter processing then, which is out of scope for this question. But keep in mind to use `mb` functions when you do this processing.